# Filtering a list in dependence of that list in clojure

Tags: clojure

Suppose you have the following code to get all primes until a parameter:

```
(defn my-filt [x z]
   (or (not= 0 (mod z x))
       (= z x)))

(defn my-filter [y x]
  (filter (partial my-filt x) y))


(defn primes [end_prime]
  (reduce my-filter
    (cons (range 2 end_prime) (range 2 end_prime))))

(primes 19)
```

As you can see I use `partial my-filt x`, because i need the list `x` in the `my-filt` function, because a filter just depends on one parameter. My question is following: Is there a better way of using idiomatic clojure not to use partial in a filter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I always prefer being explicit about what you are doing, rather than using `partial`.  For example, I would have written:

```
(filter  #(my-filt x %)  y)
```

or sometimes the full function specification:

```
(fn [z] (my-filt x z))
```

So it is clear we are calling `my-filt` with a fixed parameter `x`.  The `fn` syntax also gives you the option to provide a descriptive name for each argument, which is often quite helpful documentation for the reader.

Of course, `partial` cannot be used if you have any free arg preceeding a fixed arg.

Comment: I think this is generally good advice, but there's nothing implicit about using `partial`. It's just as explicit as an anonymous function; it's just not used very often because it's both longer and more distrcting than a lambda.